# C#: Why this Delegate invoke with argument printing wrong values

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke

I created a list of delegates and add following anonymous delegate for each value of variable `i`:

```
delegate {Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

I was expecting it to print 3 ten times because while invoking each delegate, I am passing 3 as the argument. But, it is printing 10 ten times.

Following is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowUsingDelegates();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        delegate void MyDelegate(int i);

        static void ShowUsingDelegates()
        {
            var myDelegates = new List<MyDelegate>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                myDelegates.Add(delegate {Console.WriteLine(i); });
            }

            foreach (var a in myDelegates)
            {
                a.Invoke(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you add the same delegate 10 times to your list. Then you iterate that list and call every delegate resulting in 10 calls. I can´t see your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: Why do you expect the delegate to pay any attention to anything you pass to `Invoke`. It's not defined to take *any* parameters.

Comment: Have a look at the compiled version: [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAocVoBYGKQOwIYFsBTAZwAdcBjQiAYQHtti6AbQgQVNOYEsLcAXbgyQBvJBAlQAzFABMqAOzjJYxJPWoAbFDSoAHAAoYYANoBdCLgBOAc2IBKZRoirnzgMoALOgHcAqsTc2DYAIoSsNgIkBvaYbhr0jCyEAHQASoS4ACYAMkGEMXFuAL5IThpZ4YSR/NQgugCyAJ5hEVEGQfwQ3LFlam4w2vUQXr4BQaFVNdGO/c6u8ZIAbtYQ+C1TUcQQALwQ2IQ+EHnE/AA8za3VUQB8heXxAGZ0VhAd2F3cuxBgsN0QZwg0F+3QA1KDZosVA8oWsNm1asQUmwslkDJUEdQRDAAJwdWIQYq9OaLUpYElPF6ZCieN4rV64brYOFXaYOGHzDmLXApACS2CWdAA1gUpMTYYSuWT1GTikA==)

Comment: Wrong delegate definition, then capturing the global variable for lazy evaluation, nothing is right with this code

Answer (score 3):

Your delegate is capturing the variable `i`, which, after your loop, will be 10. You are ignoring the parameter of your delegate (3 in this case). You also named this parameter `i` in your delegate declaration, but this does not matter if you ignore it when creating a new delegate instance.

Try this instead:

```
myDelegates.Add(delegate(int x) { Console.WriteLine(x); });
```

Comment: Correct, but a little more modern: `Add(x => Console.WriteLine(x))`

Comment: @bommelding Absolutely! But wanted to avoid changing the syntax too much in case OP is new to this.